# javascript: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: javascript, angular, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement typeahead in in Angular2 app using typeahead.js. In the typescript file I added following import segment.

```
import initTypeahead = require("../../../assets/js/init/dashboard.js");
```

**dashboard.d.ts**

```
declare function initTypeahead(data:any,id:any): void;
export = initTypeahead(data,id);
```

**dashboard.js**

```
if ('undefined' !== typeof module) {

  module.exports = function initTypeahead(data, element) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(element);
    var _values = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: data
    });
    _values.initialize();

    var elt = $(element);
    elt.tagsinput({
      itemValue: 'code',
      itemText: 'value',
      typeaheadjs: {
        name: '_values',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: _values.ttAdapter()
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then in the typescript following lines are added.

```
private getCities(): void {
  this.componentsService.getCriteriaValues(this.product, "city").subscribe(res => {
    initTypeahead(res.returnData, '#city'); // error at this line

  });


}
```

Following error is showing up on **ng serve**

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Are you using Angular-cli?

Comment: @SrAxi, yes I am using angular-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Angular-CLI:

**angular-cli.json:**

```
"scripts": [
        "assets/js/init/dashboard.js"
 ],
```

**Where you are using it:**

```
import '../../../assets/js/init/dashboard.js';

declare function initTypeahead(data:any,id:any): void;
```

You first need to *load* the library from your angular-cli.json and then you can actually import that code into your component in order to use it's methods, variables, etc.